# indexed_db openCursor latest changes

Tags: dart

The following code was posted as the new handling for openCursor. Could someone please advise if the following code should work now (Dart r18915), and what is the "values" variable?

```
store.openCursor(autoAdvance: true).listen(
    (cursor) => values.add(onCursor(cursor)),
    onDone: () => completer.complete(values),
    onError: (e) => completer.completeError(e));
return completer.future;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what your `onCursor()` function is doing/calling. I'm assuming your values variable is a list.

I do something similar myself but with a callback instead of a future/completer. You only have a small function fragment here. I'm going to flush it out some to hopefully add some details:

```dart
// Accept the indexeddb Database, and return a future which
// will provide the list of values from 'someKey'
Future<List<String>> getSomeKeyValues(Database db) {
  var values = new List<String>();
  var completer = new Completer();

  var store = db.transaction('DB_STORE', 'readwrite').objectStore('DB_STORE');
  store.openCursor(autoAdvance: true).listen((cursor) {
      if(cursor != null && cursor.value != null) {
        // Note cursor.value is actually a Map<String, String> 
        // of collection's key and value
        values.add(cursor.value['someKey']); // get the value key 'someKey'
      }
    }, onDone: () => completer.complete(values),
    onError: (e) => completer.completeError(e));

  return completer.future;
}
```

We would then call this function something like this:

```dart
getSomeKeyValues(myDatabase).then((results) {
  for(var value in results) {
    print(value);
  }
}
```